# “query values must be an array” error with in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am working on a node server. I want to extract data from a local postgreSQL database. It has two tables, account and accountCLI. The below mentioned works fine with psql terminal, but shows errors “query values must be an array” when I try to access through the nodejs.

```
SELECT username, array_to_string(array(select phonenumber from accountCLI where accountCLI.ccaiuser_id = account.ccaiuser_id), ', ') as PhoneNumber, projectid FROM account;
```

This is how I initialized in nodejs

```
 const getCCAIUsers = (request, response) => {
  pool.query('SELECT username, array_to_string(array(select phonenumber from accountCLI where accountCLI.ccaiuser_id = account.ccaiuser_id), ', ') as PhoneNumber, projectid FROM account', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
}
```

When I have executed the query in postgres terminal, it works fine:

[image]

But it shows error in node.js
[image]

I have read plenty of articles and understood that it could a parameterized query, but don't know how to initialize in node environment. Please help?

Comment: You might think `', '` is part of the JS string, but in reality, it's dividing the string in two parameters. Also I think you need to pass an array before the callback.

Comment: @D.Pardal May you recommend possible alternate code in the context of JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include `'` in string delimited with `'` without a backslash before (`\'`). I believe this will work:

```js
const getCCAIUsers = (request, response) => {
  pool.query("SELECT username, array_to_string(array(select phonenumber from accountCLI where accountCLI.ccaiuser_id = account.ccaiuser_id), ', ') as PhoneNumber, projectid FROM account", [], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
}
```